# How to point intersection of lines in svg and d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have successfully drawn a grid using d3.js. The grid consists of 10 rows and 5 columns. How should I mark an intersection of row and column by using mouseOnclick? That intersection should look like I indicates that point is intersected.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500);

       
       
var inputs = [
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 50,    "y2": 50},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 90,    "y2": 90},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 130,  "y2": 130},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 170,  "y2": 170},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 210,  "y2": 210},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 250,  "y2": 250},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 290,  "y2": 290},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 330,  "y2": 330},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 370,  "y2": 370},
{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 400,  "y2": 400},



//columns
 {  "x1": 100,  "x2": 100,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 400},
 {  "x1": 200,  "x2": 200,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 400},
 {  "x1": 300,  "x2": 300,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 400}, 
 {  "x1": 400,  "x2": 400,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 400},  
 {  "x1": 500,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 400}, 
]

         svg.selectAll("line").data(inputs).enter().append("line")
         
         .attr("x1", function(d) {
           return d.x1;
         })
         .attr("x2", function(d) {
           return d.x2;
         })
         .attr("y1", function(d) {
           return d.y1;
         })
         .attr("y2", function(d) {
           return d.y2;
         })
         .attr("stroke", "red")
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mmgedax/

Answer (score 2):

You need to split your array into rows and cols and then find intersection for each point. A very basic algorithm for point intersection looks like this:

```
function calculateIntersectionPoint(line1StartX, line1StartY, line1EndX, line1EndY, line2StartX, line2StartY, line2EndX, line2EndY) {
    // if the lines intersect, the result contains the x and y of the intersection (treating the lines as infinite) and booleans for whether line segment 1 or line segment 2 contain the point
    var denominator, a, b, numerator1, numerator2, result = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        onLine1: false,
        onLine2: false
    };
    denominator = ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * (line1EndX - line1StartX)) - ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
    if (denominator == 0) {
        return result;
    }
    a = line1StartY - line2StartY;
    b = line1StartX - line2StartX;
    numerator1 = ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * a) - ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * b);
    numerator2 = ((line1EndX - line1StartX) * a) - ((line1EndY - line1StartY) * b);
    a = numerator1 / denominator;
    b = numerator2 / denominator;

    // if we cast these lines infinitely in both directions, they intersect here:
    result.x = line1StartX + (a * (line1EndX - line1StartX));
    result.y = line1StartY + (a * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
/*
        // it is worth noting that this should be the same as:
        x = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndX - line2StartX));
        y = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndY - line2StartY));
        */
    // if line1 is a segment and line2 is infinite, they intersect if:
    if (a > 0 && a < 1) {
        result.onLine1 = true;
    }
    // if line2 is a segment and line1 is infinite, they intersect if:
    if (b > 0 && b < 1) {
        result.onLine2 = true;
    }
    // if line1 and line2 are segments, they intersect if both of the above are true

    return result;
};
```

A working demo can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/8gguunnq/1/

where on intersection point a circle has been drawn. If you want to omit boundary condition then change the loop restricting as https://jsfiddle.net/8gguunnq/2/

Comment: is it possible to invert whole grid